# Java: convert seconds into day, hour, minute and seconds using TimeUnit

Tags: java, datetime, time

I am using TimeStamp class to convert seconds into Day,Hours,Minutes,Seconds. I used following code

```
public static void calculateTime(long seconds) {
        int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);        
        long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds));
        long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds));
        long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds));

        System.out.println("Day " + day + " Hour " + hours + " Minute " + minute + " Seconds " + second);

    }
```

But I am not getting right result. 
For example when I called this method as `calculateTime(3600)` it gives me the result as `Day 0 Hour 1 Minute 60 Seconds 3540` instead of `Day 0 Hour 1 Minute 0 Seconds 0`.

*What is the wrong with my logic? Please help me.*

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It should be like

```
 int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);        
 long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - (day *24);
 long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds)* 60);
 long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) *60);
```

**EDIT**
Explanation:

1. Day calculation is correct, it does not require explanation.
2. TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) will give you direct conversion from seconds to hours without consideration for days you have already calculated. Minus the hours for days you already got i.e, day*24. You now got remaining hours.
3. Same for minute and second. You need to minus the already got hour and minutes respectively.

Comment: so basically you have timestamp in variable second?

Comment: what about months & years?

Answer (score 15):

Simple method:

```
public static void calculateTime(long seconds) {
    long sec = seconds % 60;
    long minutes = seconds % 3600 / 60;
    long hours = seconds % 86400 / 3600;
    long days = seconds / 86400;

    System.out.println("Day " + days + " Hour " + hours + " Minute " + minutes + " Seconds " + sec);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do like this to only use `TimeUnit`:

```
public static void calculateTime(long seconds) {
    int day = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);
    long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) -
                 TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(day);
    long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - 
                  TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(day) -
                  TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
    long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) -
                  TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(day) -
                  TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(hours) - 
                  TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minute);
    System.out.println("Day " + day + " Hour " + hours + " Minute " + minute + " Seconds " + second);
}
```

or the slightly shorter but maybe not as intuitive

```
public static void calculateTime(long seconds) {
    int day = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);
    long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) -
                 TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(day);
    long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) -
                  TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds));
    long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) -
                  TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds));
    System.out.println("Day " + day + " Hour " + hours + " Minute " + minute + " Seconds " + second);
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for this nice answer. Sorry I have a singleoption to select right answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Adding +1 to the useful answers and selecting the one you like the best as the correct one seems like the perfect behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code i created : (For 3600 seconds it shows "Days:0 Hours:1 Minutes:0 Seconds:0")

```
public class TimeConvert 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int fsec,d,h,m,s,temp=0,i;
        fsec=3600;
        //For Days
        if(fsec>=86400)
        {
            temp=fsec/86400;
            d=temp;
            for(i=1;i<=temp;i++)
            {
                fsec-=86400;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            d=0;
        }
        //For Hours
        if(fsec>=3600)
        {
            temp=fsec/3600;
            h=temp;
            for(i=1;i<=temp;i++)
            {
                fsec-=3600;
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            h=0;
        }
        //For Minutes
        if(fsec>=60)
        {
            temp=fsec/60;
            m=temp;
            for(i=1;i<=temp;i++)
            {
                fsec-=60;
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            m=0;
        }
        //For Seconds
        if(fsec>=1)
        {
            s=fsec;            
        }
        else
        {
            s=0;
        }
        System.out.println("Days:"+d+" Hours:"+h+" Minutes:"+m+" Seconds:"+s);
    }
}
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Nice attempt. But I am using TimeUnit class, and not getting desired answer.

Comment: This is a great answer actually. A great use-case is when calculating time remaining between the present and some future target date.

Just create a new method using the code above. Calculate ``long duration = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();`` and ``long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);``. Then pass ``diffInSeconds`` as a parameter to this new method.

Remove ``fsec`` from the list of integer variables. Then delete the line ``fsec=3600;``. Either replace all instances of ``fsec`` with ``diffInSeconds`` or name the input parameter ``long fsec``.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**Late but helpful**

> get time in the format 00:00:00

```
/**
     * The time in format.
     *
     * in The Format of 00:00:00
     */

public String getTimeInFormat(long _SECONDS)
{
    if(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(_SECONDS)>0)
    {
        return  String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(_SECONDS),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(_SECONDS) -
                        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(_SECONDS)),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(_SECONDS) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(_SECONDS)));
    }
    else {
        return  String.format("%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(_SECONDS) -
                        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(_SECONDS)),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(_SECONDS) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(_SECONDS)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void calculateTime(long seconds) {

int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);        
long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) ;

long tempSec = seconds - (TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(hours) );
System.out.println("after hours calculation "+ tempSec);

long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(tempSec); 

if(tempSec > TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minute)){
    tempSec = tempSec - (TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minute) );          
}else{
    tempSec = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minute) - tempSec;
}
System.out.println("after min calculation "+ tempSec);


long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(tempSec) ;

System.out.println("Day " + day + " Hour " + hours + " Minute " + minute + " Seconds " + second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
public static String secondsToString(TimeUnit greatestUnit, long sourceDuration, TimeUnit sourceUnit) {

    int ordinal = greatestUnit.ordinal();
    if(ordinal<=sourceUnit.ordinal())
        return String.format("%02d", sourceDuration);

    final long greatestDuration = greatestUnit.convert(sourceDuration, sourceUnit);
    final long rest = sourceDuration - sourceUnit.convert(greatestDuration, greatestUnit);

    return String.format("%02d:", greatestDuration) + secondsToString(TimeUnit.values()[--ordinal], rest, sourceUnit);
}
```

or by loop

```
public static String secondsToStringByLoop(TimeUnit greatestUnit, long sourceDuration, TimeUnit sourceUnit) {

    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int ordinal = greatestUnit.ordinal();

    while(true){
        if(ordinal<=sourceUnit.ordinal()) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02d", sourceDuration));
            break;
        }

        final long greatestDuration = greatestUnit.convert(sourceDuration, sourceUnit);
//          if(greatestDuration>0 || sb.length()>0)
        sb.append(String.format("%02d:", greatestDuration));

        sourceDuration -= sourceUnit.convert(greatestDuration, greatestUnit);
        greatestUnit = TimeUnit.values()[--ordinal];
    };

    return sb.toString();
}
```

usage example:

```
String str = secondsToString(TimeUnit.DAYS, 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

function returns: "00:00:16:40" (days:hours:minutes:seconds)

```
str = UnitsConverter.secondsToString(TimeUnit.DAYS, 1000, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

returns: "00:16:40" (days:hours:minutes)

```
str = UnitsConverter.secondsToString(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

returns: "16:40" (minutes:seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Oleksandr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55364795/5082991) using TimeUnit without each specific toDays,toHours,etc. methods. But using the `java.time.Duration` class and not coupled to the TimeUnit Enum ordinal.

My use case only needed Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds with format like: "13d 2h 45m 10s"; Using just the first char of the TimeUnit name, so if use TimeUnits smaller than Seconds, might not be desirable. And I didn't want to show units that were 0 unless total duration was 0 seconds.

```
public static String toDaysHoursMinutesSeconds(Duration d) {
    final var sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Must be descending
    for (var timeUnit : List.of(TimeUnit.DAYS, TimeUnit.HOURS, TimeUnit.MINUTES, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        final long v = timeUnit.convert(d);
        if (v != 0 || (sb.isEmpty() && timeUnit == TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            sb.append(sb.isEmpty() ? "" : " ").append(v).append(Character.toLowerCase(timeUnit.name().charAt(0)));
        d = d.minus(v, timeUnit.toChronoUnit());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Example:

```
import static java.time.Duration.*;
// ...
assert "13d 2h 45m 10s".equals(toDaysHoursMinutesSeconds(ofDays(13).plus(ofHours(2)).plus(ofMinutes(45)).plus(ofSeconds(10))));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void timeCalculator(){


      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter length of time in seconds: ");
      int n = input.nextInt();
      int nDay = n/86400;
      int nHours = (n%86400)/3600;
      int nMin = ((n%86400)%3600) /60;
      int nSec =(((n%86400)%3600)%60);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("That is "+ nDay+ " day(s),"+nHours+"  hour(s), "+nMin+"  minute(s), and "+nSec+" second(s). ");
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. And the question asks about using **TimeUnit**. Which you aren't using at all.