# Converting seconds to time of day

Tags: android, ios, datetime, kotlin

I have an app on iOS and am working on porting over to android. I am having an issue with handling the time.

On iOS I store points of time using:

```
Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970-0.5)
```

and Convert it to HH:MM:SS using:

```
private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
return dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
```

On Android(Kotlin) to store the point of time I use: `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000`

And for conversion:

```
LocalTime.MIN.plus(Duration.ofSeconds(xVal)).toString())
```

The issue is that the value after being converted is 6 hours ahead(could be more or less but I only look at the HH:MM:SS). As far as I can tell, the way that I get the time on android is correct and I think the issue lies in when I am converting it. I have looked around for more methods of converting time since an an interval to time of day but I could not get it to work. Most posts are just converting seconds to HH:MM:SS and so those are right out of the question. What would the equivalent to my iOS code be?

**EDIT**
I've also tried using this method to convert it still is 6 hours off even though I am giving it a timezone:

```
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.timeInMillis = xVal * 1000L
    cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().displayName)
    Log.i("This is the cal value",cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).toString())
```

Comment: Are you in the UTC timezone? if not you need to set the timezone when you convert or else it will be off

Comment: question is already answered .. check   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357945/java-convert-seconds-into-day-hour-minute-and-seconds-using-timeunit

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan as I stated in the question that is not converting time from Unix Epoch

Comment: @tyczj How would I go about getting the current time zone and apply to the value?

Comment: A simple google search can answer how to get the time zone, here is a basic example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088778/converting-utc-dates-to-other-timezones

Answer (score 0):

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
val date = sdf.format(Date(alarm.getNextTrigger()));
```