# Java:How to find time time difference between two dates considering hours between 10 am to 8 pm only and excluding holidays

Tags: java, datetime

I have a requirement where I need to calculate the time taken by the team to complete their job. It should only consider time between 10:00 AM to 08:00 PM as working hours.Also, it should exclude any holidays in between two dates.

For example : Date of job creation is 11/June/2021 17:00:00. Total time taken as of date 12/June/2021 18:00:00 will be 11 Hours. Please find the example calculation below :

Since the working hours are from 10:00 to 20:00

for 11 June it will be 3 Hours

for 12 June till 18:00:00 it will be - 8 Hours

Total = 3+8 = 11 hours

Above is just an example. Actually it might be in Days, Hours, minutes and seconds.

Trying with below appraoch :

```
Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("06/16/2021 14:00:20");
Date endDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

private static Long findDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        Date current = startDate;
        Calendar calendar = null;
        Long seconds = 0l;
        while (current.before(endDate)) {
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(current);
            
            if(between 10 AM to 8 PM and not holiday)
            seconds++;
            
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
            current = calendar.getTime();
            
        }

        return seconds;
    }
```

finally convert total seconds into format : days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Do not longer use `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` this classes are outdated since years. Use the modern `java.time.*` API

Comment: how to identify whether time lies between 10 am to 8 pm and also need help in converting seconds to day hours min and seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to find solution for converting seconds to day, hour min and second

```
int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds); 
long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - (day 24); 
long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) 60); 
long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) *60);
```

thanks to [Java: convert seconds into day, hour, minute and seconds using TimeUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357945/java-convert-seconds-into-day-hour-minute-and-seconds-using-timeunit)